# Como buscar en datatable y obtener solo la celda buscada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

quiero buscar en su buscador y obtener tan solo la celda buscada, no toda la fila, lo que quiero lograr es igual a esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/users
la lista de usuarios esta en una tabla.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
      var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var data = table.cell('#cell-1-1').data();
     
        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
            if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
              
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                table.$('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
             
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
        } );
     
        $('#button').click( function () {
            table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
        } );
    } );
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <button id="button">Eliminar Seleccion</button>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="user">Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
               
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creo que estás comparando un poco naranjas y manzanas. Sí, los dos son tablas y los dos usan JavaScript para actualizarse y buscar... pero ni su contenido ni su organización son comparables.

En la tabla de usuarios de StackOverflow, las celdas son independientes ya que ni las filas ni las columnas tienen relación alguna (que dos usuarios aparezcan en la misma o diferente fila/columna no indica absolutamente nada). En cambio, en el DataTable que presentas las celdas son "dependientes": todas las celdas de una fila están relacionadas (es información de un mismo registro) y todas las celdas de una columna también están relacionadas (porque representan el mismo dato).

Entonces, eso de "*obtener tan solo la celda buscada*" en la misma forma del ejemplo que quieres emular, no es realmente una opción con ese DataTable (porque al menos el dato debería mantenerse en la misma columna para que no deje de tener sentido).

Lo más parecido que se me ocurre sería esconder el contenido de las celdas que no cumplan la condición de búsqueda, mientras se sigue manteniendo visible las celdas que sí la cumplen. De este modo, la celda que cumpla con el criterio de búsqueda aún se mantendrá bajo la cabecera de columna que le corresponde y podrás saber qué representa.

Esto se podría hacer leyendo el [controlador del evento](https://datatables.net/reference/event/) de dibujado (`draw`) de la DataTable. Ese evento se lanza después de que la DataTable se haya dibujado (o redibujado) como por ejemplo al hacer paginación, buscar, o filtrar por algún campo.

Aquí dejo una demostración comentada:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  // cuando se redibuje la table
  table.on( 'draw', function ( e, settings, details ) {
    // seleccionamos la tabla y el valor a buscar
    var $e = $("#example");
    var buscar = $e.parent().find("input").val().toLowerCase().trim();
    
    // ponemos todas las celdas con su color original
    $e.find("td").css("opacity", "1");
    
    // si hay una cadena de busqueda
    if (buscar != "") {
      // buscamos entre todas las celdas visibles
      $e.find("td").each(function() {
        // las que no tengan la cadena buscada
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(buscar) < 0) {
          // su texto se hara transparente
          $(this).css("opacity", "0");
        }
      });
    }
  });


  var data = table.cell('#cell-1-1').data();

  $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
      table.$('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  } );

  $('#button').click( function () {
    table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
  } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Eliminar Seleccion</button>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="user">Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson Junior</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$272,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson III</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$172,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson IV</td>
      <td>Mascot</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Software Developer</td>
      <td>Austin</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>2014/11/12</td>
      <td>$172,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Doe</td>
      <td>QA Engineer</td>
      <td>Dallas</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>2016/11/01</td>
      <td>$144,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bill Gates</td>
      <td>CEO</td>
      <td>Redmond</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>2016/11/01</td>
      <td>$144,500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Edición: Si quieres hacerlo lo más parecido a StackOverflow, puedes cambiar el CSS para que se adapte a lo que buscas, pero realmente vas a perder mucha de la funcionalidad que los DataTables te ofrecen.

La idea sería la siguiente:

- Quitar la cabecera y el pie de página
- Hacer que la filas filas se muestren de manera en línea (`inline-block`)
- Hacer que las celdas ocupen el 100% de cada fila (con `block`)
- Darle un ancho a las filas para que haya tantas como quieras en cada linea.
- Hacer que se muestren sólo múltiplos del número de filas por línea (con `pageLength`)

El resultado se vería así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({ pageLength: 9 });

  var data = table.cell('#cell-1-1').data();

  $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
      table.$('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  } );

  $('#button').click( function () {
    table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
  } );
} );
```

```css
thead, tfoot { display:none !important; }

tbody tr {
  display:inline-block;
  width:31%;
  margin:1%;
  border:1px solid black;
}

tbody tr td {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Eliminar Seleccion</button>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="user">Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson Junior</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$272,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson III</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$172,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson IV</td>
      <td>Mascot</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Software Developer</td>
      <td>Austin</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>2014/11/12</td>
      <td>$172,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Doe</td>
      <td>QA Engineer</td>
      <td>Dallas</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>2016/11/01</td>
      <td>$144,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bill Gates</td>
      <td>CEO</td>
      <td>Redmond</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>2016/11/01</td>
      <td>$144,500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Creo que no funciona la búsqueda en todas las páginas. No estoy seguro, ¿podrías comprobarlo?

Comment: Voy a mirar eso. Aunque no he cambiado la lógica interna de la búsqueda DataTables, por lo que si antes funcionaba en múltiples páginas, debería seguir haciéndolo ahora. Voy a cambiar el ejemplo para que pagine y ver si falla o no

Comment: @Guz he actualizado el código de la pregunta para que haya paginación y la búsqueda funciona bien. Por ejemplo, buscar "Tiger" (que ahora queda en la segunda página) y verás como se muestra correctamente

Comment: Excelente Alvaro, good job.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracias por la ayuda, cuando hago una busqueda se quedan celdas en blanco, el buscador de SO no queda asi, como se arreglaria?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo quiero usar para lo mismo que SO, que cada celda contenga 1 usuario, asi que creo que NO existira cabecera, que otra manera hay para desarrollar lo que quiero?, revise el codigo fuente de SO, y utilizaron table.

Comment: @hubman he actualizado la respuesta para poner un caso que funcionaría como quieres... No es ideal, pero creo que serviría para lo que buscas. Pruébalo y dime si es algo como lo que quieres.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro creo que eso me sirve, una ultima cosa como seria hacerlo de manera ideal, quiero saberlo para investigar sobre ello.

Comment: Por ejemplo, copiar el modo en el que lo hace SO, donde todos los datos del usuario están en una celda (`td`) en lugar de en una fila (`tr`) como los tienes ahora. Entonces no tendrías que preocuparte de estilos en las filas/celdas porque al hacer la búsqueda se mostrarán tal y como son correctamente (además te daría más flexibilidad a la hora de ponerlos porque no tendrías la limitación de la tabla)

Comment: Haciendo pruebas, eso tampoco funcionaría bien con DataTables, porque seguiría mostrando celdas que no corresponden (DataTables considera que todas las celdas en una fila están relacionadas). Supongo que SO está usando algún plugin para realizar la búsqueda. Deben tener algún motivo para usar tablas, personalmente creo que tendría más sentido usar `ul` (o en el caso de los rankings `ol`)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro voy a codificar con ul, deberia modificar mi pregunta?

Comment: Deberías crear una pregunta nueva porque el código (y seguramente el plugin usado) no van a ser los mismos. Si modificas la pregunta, las respuestas dejarán de tener sentido

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya formule otra pregunta, me interesa saber su opinion, http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49432/buscador-de-usuarios

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro como hacer que se muestre por decir por cada 10 usuarios?

Answer (score 2):

Buenas tardes yo con dataTable lo hago asi para recuperar los datos de las filas seleccionadas.

```
table.rows(".selected").data()
```

Aqui tienes mas documentación al respecto: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnGetFilteredData