# buscador de usuarios

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

1.- Para la búsqueda me base en el contenido de los divs, eso es una buena práctica?

2.- Cuando realizo una busqueda, y luego borro todo del input, como vuelvo a su estado inicial, es decir que se muestre todos los usuarios, existe eventos que me facilite resolver el problema?

```js
    $(function(){
       var data = [];
      $('#usuarios').children('li').each(function () {
        data.push($(this).children('div').text());
         });
     
      function igualar(buscados) {
        var palabras = [];
      
        $.each(buscados, function(idx, buscado) {
          palabras.push(buscado.toLowerCase());
        });
      return palabras;
      }
      
      function orden(a, b) {
        if (a.normal > b.normal) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (a.normal < b.normal) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
      
     function existe(elem, lista){
        for(var i=0;i<lista.length; i++){
          if(lista[i]==elem){
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      
      function eliminarDivs(posibles){
          
          $('#usuarios').children('li').each(function () {
          if(!existe($(this).children('div').text(),posibles)){
            var ide= $(this).children('div').attr('id');
          document.getElementById(ide).parentNode.remove();
          } 
          });
      }

      data = igualar(data);
     
      data.sort(orden);
      
      $("#nombre").on("input",function() {
        var key = document.getElementById("nombre").value,
            posibles = [],
            lucky = false;

        key =key.toLowerCase();

        $.each(data, function(idx, word) {

          if (word.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            posibles.push(word);
            
            if (key === word) {
              lucky = word;
            }

          }
        });
        eliminarDivs(posibles);
      });
    })
```

```css
#usuarios li{
display:inline-block;
}
li{
width:30%;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
}
li:hover{
background:#b6b5e7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    Escribe para buscar usuarios:
    <input type="text" id="nombre">

<ul id="usuarios">
  <li><div id="1">miesha</div></li>
  <li><div id="2">ronda</div></li>
  <li><div id="3">thor</div></li>
  <li><div id="4">superman</div></li>
  <li><div id="5">batman</div></li>
  <li><div id="6">susan</div></li>
  <li><div id="7">minerva</div></li>
  <li><div id="8">pedro</div></li>
  <li><div id="9">diana</div></li>
  <li><div id="10">fedor</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. No hay mayor inconveniente con utilizar el contenido de los DIV para crear tu arreglo de valores. Yo le agregaría al final la función trim() para eliminar cualquier espacio al inicio y al final.
2. Si vas a reutilizar los valores mostrados, te recomiendo que no quites los elementos, sino que los ocultes utilizando la **función de jQuery hide() y show().**

```js
    $(function(){
       var data = [];
      $('#usuarios').children('li').each(function () {
        data.push($(this).children('div').text());
         });
     
      function igualar(buscados) {
        var palabras = [];
      
        $.each(buscados, function(idx, buscado) {
          palabras.push(buscado.toLowerCase());
        });
      return palabras;
      }
      
      function orden(a, b) {
        if (a.normal > b.normal) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (a.normal < b.normal) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
      
     function existe(elem, lista){
        for(var i=0;i<lista.length; i++){
          if(lista[i]==elem){
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      
      function eliminarDivs(posibles){
          
          $('#usuarios').children('li').each(function () {
          if(!existe($(this).children('div').text(),posibles)){
            $(this).hide();
          } 
          else $(this).show();
          });
      }

      data = igualar(data);
     
      data.sort(orden);
      
      $("#nombre").on("input",function() {
        var key = document.getElementById("nombre").value,
            posibles = [],
            lucky = false;

        key =key.toLowerCase();

        $.each(data, function(idx, word) {

          if (word.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            posibles.push(word);
            
            if (key === word) {
              lucky = word;
            }

          }
        });
        eliminarDivs(posibles);
      });
    })
```

```css
#usuarios li{
display:inline-block;
}
li{
width:30%;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
}
li:hover{
background:#b6b5e7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    Escribe para buscar usuarios:
    <input type="text" id="nombre">

<ul id="usuarios">
  <li><div id="1">miesha</div></li>
  <li><div id="2">ronda</div></li>
  <li><div id="3">thor</div></li>
  <li><div id="4">superman</div></li>
  <li><div id="5">batman</div></li>
  <li><div id="6">susan</div></li>
  <li><div id="7">minerva</div></li>
  <li><div id="8">pedro</div></li>
  <li><div id="9">diana</div></li>
  <li><div id="10">fedor</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: gracias, pero mi primer pregunta no respondiste

Comment: Tienes razón. Modifiqué mi respuesta para que tengas mi opinión sobre tu primera pregunta.

Answer (score 5):

Espero te sirva,

```js
$(function(){
       var data = [];
      $('#usuarios').children('li').each(function () {
        data.push($(this).children('div').text());
         });
     
      function igualar(buscados) {
        var palabras = [];
      
        $.each(buscados, function(idx, buscado) {
          palabras.push(buscado.toLowerCase());
        });
      return palabras;
      }
      
      function orden(a, b) {
        if (a.normal > b.normal) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (a.normal < b.normal) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
      
      
      
      
     function existe(elem, lista){
        for(var i=0;i<lista.length; i++){
          if(lista[i]==elem){
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      
      function eliminarDivs(posibles){
          $('#usuarios').children('li').removeClass('invisible')
          $('#usuarios').children('li').each(function () {
               if(!existe($(this).children('div').text(),posibles)){
            var ide= $(this).children('div').attr('id');
            $('#'+ide).parent().hide()
          } else {
            var ide= $(this).children('div').attr('id');
            $('#'+ide).parent().show()
          }
          });
      }

      data = igualar(data);
     
      data.sort(orden);
      
      $("#nombre").on("input",function() {
        var key = document.getElementById("nombre").value,
            posibles = [],
            lucky = false;

        key =key.toLowerCase();

        $.each(data, function(idx, word) {

          if (word.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            posibles.push(word);
            
            if (key === word) {
              lucky = word;
            }

          }
        });
        eliminarDivs(posibles);
      });
    })
```

```css
#usuarios li{
display:inline-block;
}
li{
width:30%;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
}
li:hover{
background:#b6b5e7;
}
.invisible {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    buscar usuario:
    <input type="text" id="nombre">

<ul id="usuarios">
  <li><div id="1">miesha</div></li>
  <li><div id="2">ronda</div></li>
  <li><div id="3">thor</div></li>
  <li><div id="4">superman</div></li>
  <li><div id="5">batman</div></li>
  <li><div id="6">susan</div></li>
  <li><div id="7">minerva</div></li>
  <li><div id="8">pedro</div></li>
  <li><div id="9">diana</div></li>
  <li><div id="10">fedor</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: mi primer pregunta no respondiste, gracias

Comment: [Lo dicho en la pregunta de SQL](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49420/mysql-update-innerjoin#comment86737_49424). No deberias responder a preguntas como esta ya que es muy amplia. unos miunutos y ya tiene 2 respuestas. Además ni explicas que has cambiado ni el porqué.

Comment: @lois6b muy amplia? me explicas porque?

Comment: @hubman o amplia u opinion personal, porque cada uno puede darte una solucion de lo que considera "una buena practica" al ser subjetivo y basado en la experiencia. otra cosa seria preguntar por algo objetivo como un diseño de software en concreto. Lo mismo para la segunda pregunta

Comment: @lois6b edite mi pregunta, en inciso 2, espero que este mejor, gracias por la observacion

Comment: @hubman me alegra que te lo tomes bien. mi unica intencion es una buena calidad en las preguntas para ser un sitio de calidad.

Answer (score 1):

No se como manejes muchas de tus partes pero tengo algo distinto que podría ayudarte.

Primero hacer la consulta con la cual te haga la lista de usuarios y la información del páginador.

```
@Filtro VARCHAR(100),
@Pagina INT ,
@RegistrosPorPagina INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  WITH Usuarios
  AS(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(IdUsuario) AS RowNumber              
          ,Idem.Nombre
        FROM UsuariosTabla            
        WHERE   
         (
                (Nombre LIKE  '%' + ISNULL(@Filtro, '') + '%' )
                OR (IdUsuario LIKE  '%' + ISNULL(@Filtro, '') + '%' )
        )

  )
  SELECT (SELECT COUNT (IdUsuario) FROM Usuarios) AS TotalRegistros ,
            * FROM Usuarios
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ( @Pagina - 1 ) * @RegistrosPorPagina + 1
                  AND     ( @Pagina * @RegistrosPorPagina )

END
```

Después en tu capa de datos, usar un modelo de lista para los usuarios y un modelo objeto de páginación

```
public IEnumerable<ModUsuario> GetInbox(ModInbox objBusqueda,ref ClsModPaginacion objModPaginacion, out ClsModErrorBase objModErrorBase)
    {
        List< ModUsuario>  lstUsuarios = new List<ModUsuario>();
        objModErrorBase = new ClsModErrorBase();
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = null;
        try
        {
            ICollection<SqlParameter> lstSqlParameter = new List<SqlParameter>();
            lstSqlParameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@Filtro", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(objBusqueda.Filtro) ? string.Empty : objBusqueda.Filtro });
            lstSqlParameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@Pagina", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = objModPaginacion.Pagina });
            lstSqlParameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@RegistrosPorPagina", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = objModPaginacion.RegistrosPorPagina });
            sqlDataReader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(this.strConexion, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "_492.spdOpinGetLstUsuario", lstSqlParameter.ToArray());
            if (sqlDataReader != null)
            {
                if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (objModPaginacion.TotalRegistros == 0)
                        {
                            objModPaginacion.Asignar(decimal.Parse(sqlDataReader["TotalRegistros"].ToString()));
                        }
                        var objUsuario = new ClsModOpinEncIdentificacion()
                        {
                            IdUsuarioCreacion = (int)(sqlDataReader["IdUsuario"] != DBNull.Value ? sqlDataReader["IdUsuario"] : 0),
                            Nombre = (string)(sqlDataReader["Nombre"] != DBNull.Value ? sqlDataReader["Nombre"] : string.Empty)
                        };
                        lstUsuarios.Add(objUsuario);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { objModErrorBase.MsgError = ex.Message; }
        finally { sqlDataReader?.Close(); }
        return lstUsuarios;
    }
```

y estos objetos cargados los puedes enviar hacia tu vista para renderizar el páginador y tu tabla de usuarios. Ese lo dejo a tu forma.

```
<Paginador></Paginador>
<tabla></tabla>
<Paginador></Paginador>
```

Solo para darte una ayuda, el páginador puede ser alg así

```
@if (Model.TotalPaginas == 0)
{
    <div>No se encontraron resultados</div>
}
else
{
<div>
    @if (Model.MostrarPaginacion)
    {


        <ul class="pagination" id="pagination">
            <li>
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="aPagina" href="Model.Action, Model.Controller, new { Pagina = 1 }">
                    |<
                </a>
            </li>
            @foreach (var pagina in Model.LstPaginas)
            {

                if (Model.PaginaActual == pagina)
                {
                    <li class="active">
                        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="aPagina" href="@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.Controller, new { Pagina = pagina })">
                            @pagina
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {

                    <li>
                        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="aPagina" href="@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.Controller,  new { Pagina = pagina })">
                            @pagina
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }

            }
            <li>
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="aPagina" href="Model.Action, Model.Controller,  new { Pagina =@Model.TotalPaginas }">
                    >|
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    }
</div>
}
```