# paginacion de li

Tags: javascript, html5

quiero paginar los siguiente `li`

```
<ul id="usuarios">
  <li><div id="1">miesha</div></li>
  <li><div id="2">ronda</div></li>
  <li><div id="3">thor</div></li>
  <li><div id="4">superman</div></li>
  <li><div id="5">batman</div></li>
  <li><div id="6">susan</div></li>
  <li><div id="7">minerva</div></li>
  <li><div id="8">pedro</div></li>
  <li><div id="9">diana</div></li>
  <li><div id="10">fedor</div></li>
</ul>
```

y mi js es:

```
$(function() {
                $("#usuarios").pagination({
                    items: 100,
                    itemsOnPage: 5,
                    cssStyle: 'light-theme'
                });
            });
```

importando el js y css

```
script(src="/javascripts/jquery.simplePagination.js")
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/simplePagination.css')
```

estoy siguiendo este tutorial:
http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

no funciona nada de la lista, todo desaparecio. solamente se visualiza los botones

en que estoy fallando?

Comment: donde dices, "importanto el js y css" ... no lo haces con el formato `"<script src="` ? Te da algun tipo de error por consola ?

Comment: debiera decirte `script is not a function` y `link is not a function`

Comment: @amenadiel no sale ningun error, simplemente se deforma totalmente,

Comment: @lois6b estoy usando jade por eso lo importo de esa manera

Comment: y estás seguro que la ruta relativa te la está cogiendo ?

Comment: @lois6b no estaba cogiendolo, pero ahora solamente se muestra los botones de paginacion y desaparecieron los `li`

Comment: @lois6b en realidad lo que quiero hacer con la paginacion es mostrar de 10 en 10 usuarios de este tema http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49432/buscador-de-usuarios, creo que como lo estoy haciendo no se pueda, por que cada li esta supuestamente en cada boton y eso no quiero, lo que quiero es que se muestre cada 10 usuarios

Answer (score 2):

Hola para Realizar lo que deseas te aconsejo revises este [Ejemplo](http://listjs.com/examples/pagination/), y no tendrías necesidad de hacer uso de la simplePagination.js.

Aplicando el ejemplo que te doy a lo que tu planteas, tu codigo HTML quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/list.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="test-list">
      <input type="text" class="search" />
      <ul class="list" id="usuarios">
      <li><div id="1">miesha</div></li>
      <li><div id="2">ronda</div></li>
      <li><div id="3">thor</div></li>
      <li><div id="4">superman</div></li>
      <li><div id="5">batman</div></li>
      <li><div id="6">susan</div></li>
      <li><div id="7">minerva</div></li>
      <li><div id="8">pedro</div></li>
      <li><div id="9">diana</div></li>
      <li><div id="10">fedor</div></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="pagination"></ul>
  </div>
```

En el Body de tu pagina, debes incorporar un pequeño script el cual te detallo a continuación:

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(e) {
       var monkeyList = new List('test-list', {
       valueNames: ['name'],
       page: 3,
       pagination: true
     });
    });
   </script>
```

Incorpora en tu style.css:

```
.pagination li {
   display:inline-block;
   padding:5px;
}
```

De esta manera el resultado de tu paginacion quedaría de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El uso de este método a diferencia del que tu planteas (simplePagination.js) no guarda ninguna relación con que este sea mucho mejor que el otro, solo es cuestión de gustos, este en particular forma parte de mi experiencia. Saludos espero te sirva!

Comment: Las respuestas en las que se refiere a un recurso externo sin mayor explicación se consideran de baja calidad. Si el recurso referido es extenso, al menos incluyo un síntesis y explica si has usado ese recurso o por qué lo recomiendas.

Comment: Tienes Razón muchas Gracias!